# What is the difference between these two SQL Server queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

I have two queries in SQL Server.

First query:

```
Select * 
From Stack, Overflow
Where Stack.Id = Overflow.StackId
```

Second query:

```
Select * 
From Stack 
Inner Join Overflow On Overflow.StackId = Stack.Id
```

These two queries return the same results.

So what is the difference between this two queries in terms of performance?

And which one do you prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use query #2 - it's the proper **ANSI/ISO SQL Standard** `JOIN` syntax, and is preferred over #1.

For one: your JOIN condition is where it belongs - on the `JOIN` - and doesn't clutter up your `WHERE` clause. Your `WHERE` clause should contain only things that you actually use to constrain your result set.

And secondly: since you have to define your `JOIN` condition on the JOIN, you're less likely to "forget" about it and unwantingly produce a cartesian product.

And lastly: since you define `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, your query becomes more readable and easier to udnerstand - for someone else looking at your query, and for yourself in six months when you have to go back and maintain your code.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the first query is *implicitly* joining two tables, where the second is *explicitly* joining two tables.

I prefer the second one, just because you're being <strike>verbose</strike> explicit in stating exactly how two tables are joined together.  I suppose you are in the first one as well, but as the query grows it would get a lot harder to read.

Performance will mostly depend on your table indexes.

Comment: Rather than *verbose*, I would say *explicit*.

Comment: @RedFilter I actually used *explicit* in the original text, but I felt I was saying that word too much so I changed it.  =)